# fix sudo access on Google Cloud Ubuntu 18 instance

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, google-cloud-platform

I edited `/etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` to remove password free sudo access. I use SSH access keys to log in and (apparently) I don't know the login password. Which means I have locked myself out of root access to the server.

Any thoughts on how to recover without rebuilding my instance? Is there something I can do in the cloud console?

(Edit: Is is on the Google cloud platform.  It's in the tags but not in the text)

Comment: Restore from an image.

Comment: What provider are you using? DigitalOcean offers an option to reset root password automatically.

Comment: On the google cloud platform.  It was in the tags, but not the text.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to deal with. What you do is, using the Google Cloud Console, add a startup script that's run at higher than root privileges, this 'resets' sudo to run in a 'safe mode'.

1. Start at VM instances
2. Click the VM instance under 'name' column
3. Click 'Edit' at the top
4. Scroll down to bottom to 'Automation'
5. In the box 'Startup script' paste the following:

```
   mv /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.backup.$(date +"%s") && echo "%google-sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers && chown 0:0 /etc/sudoers && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

6. Restart the VM instance to run the above startup script
7. SSH to the VM instance, to the CLI as normal. Sudo is in a kind of 'safe mode'
8. Fix whatever the problems had broke sudo, using sudo visudo as needed
   i.e.

```
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/broken-one
```

or

```
   sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.backup.xxxxxxxxxxx
```

9. Restore the original now bug-free /etc/sudoers like this:

```
   sudo mv /etc/sudoers.backup.xxxxxxxxxx /etc/sudoers
```

Sudo is now fixed.
The startup script can be removed if no longer required

Comment: When sudo is broken this works to get you out of the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

If you've corrupted the `sudoers` file and have no SSH access, you've likely locked yourself out of the machine.

> I edited /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users

Use the `passwd` command to do this. There's no reason to edit these files by hand.

---

It's worth connecting through the [GCE Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to see if you can get access to what you need, but I don't know if you'll be able to escalate to root without a valid superuser. If the disk isn't encrypted, you could unmount the disk and try to fix the file manually from a different VM.

Comment: I was hoping maybe there was a way to recover it via the Google Cloud Console.   I have since rebuilt the instance.

Comment: As a last-ditch, you can try setting up the Serial Console and see if it gives you access to what you need: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console. It's worth a shot.

Comment: I had tried the console.  I broke sudoers bad enough that I couldn't escalate there either :(